# SQL select query to return one row for data with or without fragile

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a shipping table with some shipments have fragile material and others don't. I would like to return only one row for each shipment either Fragile or not. I'm using a case statement and right now it breaks it into two rows for the shipments that have both Fragile and non-Fragile materials. Can you please suggest any method to do this?

`,Case when mat.Frag = 'F'  then 'YES' else 'N/A' end as Fragil`e

I'm already using groups an this column is also in group by clause

Comment: post your query and sample data please

Comment: You'll need to post more information. What is the table structure?, sample data?, desired result?

Comment: It seems you have more than one related records in table for your key. In case you are expecting only one, i would suggest to write subQuery which will return single value

Comment: so what should be on `Fragile` if the are 2 records one with +  one without?

Comment: Actually each delivery has lines and some deliveries have both fragile and non fragile items for those the result set was breaking it into two rows one with Fragile as F and the rest without F.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it
I can use:
Case When exists( Select mat.Frag from Materials
      where mat.Frag = 'F')
then 'F' else '' End as Fragile

Comment: This does sound about right, though without sample data there's little that anyone can help you with